# How can I tell if an Access Form/Report Section supports the OnRetreat property/Retreat Event?

Tags: ms-access, com, event-handling, vba

An Access Form and/or Report can have multiple sections (eg. Report Header, Page Header, Detail, etc.), and each can be retrieved using `Report.SectionName` where `SectionName` is user-defined, or using the `Report.Section(Index)` property, where the `Index` is an Access defined constant for the first 9 sections, and an incrementing index for any additional sections, as per [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192668.aspx)

Regardless of the section index, the property returns a Section object, and a Section object supports an OnRetreat property.

But when I inspect the VBA code-behind the sections of a report, the VBE does not expose an `OnRetreat` event for the PageHeader or PageFooter sections. And if I try to inspect the `OnRetreat` property, I get a run-time error:

> Run-time error '2455':
>
> You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the
>   property OnRetreat.

Is this just some internal trickery by Access/VBE, or is there a way that I can programmatically determine if a Section supports OnRetreat?

I know I can use `On Error Resume Next` to skip over the error, but I'm more interested in knowing if there is a property that can determine if a section supports `OnRetreat` and/or if there is a way to determine the section type, given a Section instance.

Is suspect I'll have to write something that mimics the internal Access-logic, like this:

```
Private Function SupportsOnRetreat(ReportSection As section) As Boolean

  Dim rpt As Report
  Set rpt = ReportSection.Parent

  SupportsOnRetreat = Not Report.section(AcSection.acPageHeader) Is ReportSection _
                      And Not Report.section(AcSection.acPageFooter) Is ReportSection

End Function
```

**EDIT:** I did find the `[_SectionInReport]` and `[_PageHdrFtrInReport]` interfaces, but all Sections seem to implement both interfaces.